# C++ Unit Test Hanging

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am testing some code with Visual Studio's built in Unit test framework for C++. The test just call the following routine and then does an `Assert::AreEqual(returned_value, (float)1)`however, all other tests run and this just hangs. I can't see why the loops would be infinite loops, but I am likely missing something. Thanks.

```
vector< vector<float> > history;
vector< vector<float> > graph;

float calculateDeviation(int period) {
    int x1 = history.front()[0];
    int x2 = x1 + period;
    int i = 0, minimum, maximum, SSres = 0, SStot = 0, j=0, R2 =0;
    float  average = 0;
    while (x2 <= history.back()[0]) {
        average += averageGradient(x1, x2);
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = + period;
    }

    x1 = history.front()[0];
    x2 = x1 + period;
    i++;
    while (j < i) {
        SSres += pow((graph[i][0]-((graph[i][2]*graph[i][0])+graph[i][3])), 2);
        SStot += pow(graph[i][0] - average, 2);
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = + period;
        j++;
    }

    R2 = 1 - (SSres / SStot);
    return R2;
}
```

The following values are measured & returned in the unit test. 
`history.size() = 15`
`history[5].size() = 14`
`graph.size() = 14`
`graph[1].size() = 4`

Comment: `x2 = + period;` Did you mean `x2 += period;`? (Add the value of `period` to `x2`.)

Comment: What's the type of `history`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson it's a vector

Comment: @BoBTFish Yes! Thanks for spotting that, I'll see if that fixes it.

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's a bunch of unknowns that could screw things up here, what's `history.back()` and what does that return? Does it return at all? What about the other functions that are called? What value does `period` have? There's probably more unknowns that are relevant.

Comment: @skyking I have added details of the global vectors and their sizes `period` is being used as 3600 for testing, but could be anything in my real project. The code which populates these vectors is fairly extensive, so I think it would confuse this if posted.

Comment: You have Visual C++ - step through with the debugger and see what it's doing. Step into each loop and watch the loop variables to see what's going on directly. There will come times in your programming career where the debugger is of no value. This is NOT one of those times.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Still not nearly complete. But have you tried Michael Kohne's suggestion and use the debugger to see where it hangs? Either it will be stuck in one of the loops or in a function that is being called.